# which is the equivalence of measurements in cm or mm for DOMPDF

Tags: laravel, pdf, dompdf, barryvdh

I am using laravel, barryvdh / laravel-dompdf to generate a pdf.
But I need to configure my paper size to measurements the customer.

which is the equivalence of measurements in cm or mm.

I configure some measures, I found:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('view.factura', ['data'=>$data] )->setPaper([0,0,500,1000]);
```

but I need to export it in paper size:

10.16 cm x 33 cm.

in setPaper([0,0,500,1000] = what would be the equivalence to organize my measurements

what would the equivalence be? where can i learn from this?
Thank you.

Can this tool help me?
https://www.blitzresults.com/es/pixel/

setting my pdf to 150dpi?

```
->setOptions(['dpi' => 150, 'isRemoteEnabled' => true])->setPaper([0,0,600,1949])
```

¿are this measurements equivalence: 10.16 cm x 33 cm  = 600 x 1949?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dompdf seems to use [`points`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)) as measuring unit.so you can convert it into points using
some cm to point converters like
[Online cm to point converter](http://www.unitconversion.org/typography/centimeters-to-points-computer-conversion.html)

and so please try this code

```
 $pdf = PDF::loadView('view.factura', ['data'=>$data] )
   ->setOptions(['dpi' => 150, 'isRemoteEnabled' => true])
    ->setPaper([0,0,288,935.43])
```

And dpi has nothing to do with paper size.

Comment: @wil did this help you...please reply